# Ruby: undefined method for not initialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> Note: There are numerous answers explaining that you can get this error when you subclass `ActiveRecord::Base` and add an `#initialize` without `super`. No answer explains what is actually happening.

I am working in someone else's code and I have an HTTParty service in a Rails app with the following class hierarchy. Note the subclass `#initialize` with a differing signature to the parent class.

```
module A
  class Base
    include HTTParty
    ...
  end
end

module A
  class User < Base

    def initialize(user)
      @user = user
    end
  end
end

module A
  class PublicUser < User

    def initialize(opts = {})
      @limit = opts[:limit]
      # no call to super
    end
  end
end
```

Locally there are no problems with this, but in SemaphoreCI the following results:

```
A::PublicUser.new(limit: 1).some_method
undefined method `some_method' for #<A::PublicUser not initialized>
```

I can't find any documentation about the "not initialized" message. What causes this sort of failure?

Comment: Is this a plain ruby, or rails?

Comment: The classes causing the error are all plain ruby. But it is being called in a Rails application.

Comment: Have you explicitly required all files?

Comment: I have not. I believe that issue would return a "NameError: uninitialized constant X" error though.

Comment: @coreyward why have you removed [tag:ruby-on-rails] tag, despite the fact that it’s rails ruines everything, and produces that silly error message?

Comment: @mudasobwa The question didn't mention Rails and it seemed like your justification (“since plain good ruby would rare give such a weird behaviour”) was lacking. I see that Rails is involved and that the tag has been re-added now, so all good. Cheers!

Comment: For what it's worth, there are two missing `end` statements here.

Comment: @coreyward thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I got it. I also tagged your question with [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails), since plain good ruby would rare give such a weird behaviour.

You have experienced two different issues, more or less unrelated.

1. `#<A::PublicUser not initialized>` is a result of (sic!) calling [`inspect`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c0c331bfc8ba66efa310c1c065e3b6349d97d9b2/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L497) on `A::PublicUser`. So, ruby tries to format an error message and—voilà—the class is printed out that way.
2. Rails messes with you, as well as with constant lookup. `A::Base` name conflicts with `ActiveRecord::Base`, and guess what is resolved when `class User < Base` is met. To replicate this behaviour you might open a console and do: `class Q < ActiveRecord::Base; end; Q.allocate`, resulting in `#<Q not initialized>`. (Do you already love Rails as I do?)
3. To fix this, either explicitly specify `class User < A::Base` or rename `Base` to `MyBase`. Sorry for suggesting that.

Comment: Okay, this tells me what's going on with my code, but I still don't understand what's happening more generally. Maybe your first point is covering that. Did the call to `.new` fail, and `inspect` was called on... what?

Comment: I believe, the call to `new` did not fail, rather it created a subclass of `ActiveRecord::Base` class, which in turn lacks the `some_method` method.

Comment: Hm. And "not initialized" is an ActiveRecord error you get when you call a method that was not a key in the initialization object? (or something)

Comment: "not initialized" is not an error. "not initialized" is a silly `inspect` output produced by rails.

Comment: Interesting. Could you add that to your answer? Not sure why you were downvoted, I think this gives me the information I need.

Comment: This information already added—item 1) even contains a link to the exact place in rails source that prints this `"not initialized"` garbage. Also, please add the [tag:ruby-on-rails] tag back, I hope this silent guy will stop messing up if you would fix tags there yourself.